# Word object changing after pushing onto stack Java

Tags: java, object, constructor

```
while(!paths.isEmpty()){
    BoggleSearchState2 path = paths.pop();

    if(dictionary.contains(path.getWord()) && !foundWords.contains(path.getWord())){
            foundWords.add(path.getWord());
    }

    int[][] grid = path.getGrid();
    int row = path.getRow();
    int column = path.getColumn();
    Letter[][] game = path.getGame();

    if(row < (grid.length-1) && grid[row+1][column] == 0) {
        paths.push(new BoggleSearchState2(path.getWordWord(), game[(row+1)][column], game));
    }
}
```

My BoggleSearchState2 constructor is overloaded like this:

```
public BoggleSearchState2(Letter l, Letter[][] gameIn) {
    game = gameIn;
    word = new Word(l);
    grid = initialGrid(l);
    row = l.getPoint().y;
    column = l.getPoint().x;
    stringWord = wordToString(word);

}

public BoggleSearchState2(Word wordIn, Letter l, Letter[][] gameIn){
    game = gameIn;
    word = new Word(wordIn.getLetters());
    word.addLetter(l);
    grid = genGrid(word, game);
    row = l.getPoint().y;
    column = l.getPoint().x;
    stringWord = wordToString(word);

}
```

With my class variables like this:

```
public class BoggleSearchState2 {

    private Word word;
    private Letter[][] game;
    private int[][] grid;
    private String stringWord;
    private int row, column;
```

The problem i am having is that after i push the new BoggleSS2, my path.word changes and adds another letter object.  i do not know how this is happening.  can anyone tell me why?

```
public class Word {

private ArrayList<Letter> word;

public Word(Letter l) {
    word = new ArrayList<Letter>();
    word.add(l);
}
public Word(ArrayList<Letter> listLetters, Letter l){
    word = listLetters;
    word.add(l);
}
public Word(ArrayList<Letter> letters) {
    word = letters;
}
```

Comment: What is the `Word` class?

Comment: Word class is basically just an ArrayList of Letter objects.

Comment: It looks like you are just copying references around, so changes in contents will be reflected everywhere. You need to copy the contents. try `word = new Word(new ArrayList(wordIn.getLetters()));` in the constructor.